# ASP.NET MVC 5 with Angular 6-7 and no Node.js

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, angular5, angular6, angular7, typescript3.0

I need to integrate Angular 6 or 7 (latest version at the time of this writing is 7.0.3) with an ASP.NET MVC 5 application (.NET Framework 4.5+, no .NET Core).

Is Node.js a "must have" in order to run Angular? I need to install the "smallest possible environment" to achieve my goal.

I must also use TypeScript (v3) but not Javascript. Is that possible? Any suggestions?

Many thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** I looked for a VS 2017 Community Edition project template but most of them are for .NET Core. It would be great if you point to a download location of such a template (ASP.NET MVC 5, TypeScript, Angular 5-7, no Node.js).